# Editing model with Ember-data and Rails not saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ember.js, ember-data, active-model-serializers

I am attempting to edit a user with ember-data and rails, when I edit the user information and try to do a model.save() I get a

```
unexpected end of input
```

error in my console.
It looks like there is a weird query going on in the Rails side. Here is the query from Rails:

```
Started PUT "/users/2" for ::1 at 2015-04-11 15:59:17 -0500
 Processing by UsersController#update as HTML
 Parameters: {"user"=>{"username"=>"adminUser", "email"=>"admin@test.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "admin"=>true}, "id"=>"2"}
 User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
 ApiKey Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "api_keys".* FROM "api_keys" WHERE (expired_at >= '2015-04-11 20:59:17.113883') AND "api_keys"."access_token" = $1  ORDER BY "api_keys"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["access_token", "500b9b5d38ecb9f851b89823d5b40d0f"]]

 User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]

 ApiKey Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "api_keys".* FROM "api_keys" WHERE "api_keys"."user_id" = $1 AND (expired_at >= '2015-04-11 20:59:17.117827')  ORDER BY "api_keys"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 2]]
 (0.2ms)  BEGIN
 User Exists (0.6ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE (LOWER("users"."username") = LOWER('adminUser') AND "users"."id" != 2) LIMIT 1
 User Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE (LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('admin@test.com') AND "users"."id" != 2) LIMIT 1
 (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
```

I can't figure why Rails would be trying to select !=2 like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are validations that are failing. You're updating the User with id 2, and I'm betting that you have uniqueness validations on `username` and `email`. The problem is that there is another `User` record with at least the same e-mail address, which is causing the rollback.

You should probably also make sure that you're returning status `422 (Unprocessable Entity)` with appropriate errors when an update fails.

Comment: Thank you! It wasn't actually any validation errors, but Ember is trying to send a password of `nil`.

Comment: That'd do it! Glad you found the issue. Password presence is a validation too. :)